# reshape2 - dcast error transposing ~650k rows

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I am trying to transpose some data by time stamp using reshape2 / dcast.

```
> head(df1)
              rule         rawdt count                  dt index
1 #31Gifts:31Gifts 2014-11-25T03     1 2014-11-25 03:00:00     1
2 #31Gifts:31Gifts 2014-11-26T16     1 2014-11-26 16:00:00     1
3 #31Gifts:31Gifts 2014-11-16T05     2 2014-11-16 05:00:00     1
4 #31Gifts:31Gifts 2014-11-16T14     1 2014-11-16 14:00:00     1
5 #31Gifts:31Gifts 2014-11-26T00    23 2014-11-26 00:00:00     1
6 #31Gifts:31Gifts 2014-11-19T03     1 2014-11-19 03:00:00     1
```

When I run dcast I get this error:

```
> wide<-dcast(df1, dt~index, value.var="count")
Error in if (n > 2^31) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Can anyone offer suggestions?  I did create the dates from the original string format using this command:

```
df$dt<-strptime(df$rawdt, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H")
```

Could the POSIXlt dates be causing an issue?

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with **dplyr**?

Comment: sorry i got my packages mixed up. this is the reshape2 package

Comment: Can you include the results of `traceback()`?